# Will doing a chargeback on tuition hurt my chances at getting into the same university for grad school?

Tags: tuition

I'm taking an independent phys ed course at my local university. I'm also currently studying for the GRE and I'm hoping to start grad school here in a totally different department in fall 2021. There's a professor I really like and have a good connection with here so I'm pretty set on this university.

The instructor cancelled the course after one class due to low enrollment, and the university is saying that since it started, it's too late for a refund on the $650 fee. I've called and tried to get a refund but their HR/registration department won't budge.

I paid with a credit card and I'm considering doing a chargeback. Would this hurt my chances at getting into the grad school later on, and I should just let myself be robbed?

Comment: Are you in the US? If the instructor cancelled that is totally different than you dropping. Have you spoken with the department chair or dean?  They may be able to advocate for a refund. If they won't  I would write a letter explaining what happened and send it to someone in upper administration.

Comment: Sounds like the kind of problem that can be solved by simply talking nicely to people, and bringing the unrequested evidence (proof that the course got cancelled, proof that you've paid for it and so on). Don't let yourself be robbed, but keep a very cool mind in the process. Also, there is no need to have legal proof, a video made by you and the instructor explaining the course was canceled is not so hard to do, and is very strong proof for your purpose.

Comment: Was this the only class you registered for? Is the $850 fee for tuition only or does it include other fees like health service/insurance, activity fees, etc? Is it a required class for you to graduate? Do you plan to graduate this term?

Comment: My reading of your question assumes that you are a non-degree student and have enrolled only for this course (you may have already graduated from this institution with a degree prior to enrolling in this non-degree course, but that is not really pertinent). Can you clarify if my assumption is correct or not? From some of the other comments/answers this seems to not be clear between myself and others.

Comment: If loudly going up the ladder of administrators all the way to the dean of students doesn't work, I'd encourage you to consider small claims instead of a chargeback. There's a decent chance the credit card company will side with the school (as they'll provide evidence you signed up and that the class started, winning the dispute); a small claims judge will very probably quickly side with you.

Comment: I agree with ceejayoz.  Also, you have two years to file with Small Claims court. With a charge-back, you don't have much time to act. And wih a charge-back, they could still retaliate against you. With a court judgement, they won't be able to.

Comment: @Mefitico a video? What do you mean? Why would you make a video instead of asking the instructor to write a letter? What would you even do with the video? If I were the administrator and forced to sit through a video for something I could have easily read, I'd be pretty annoyed.

Comment: @terdon : Fair point. First I'm assuming that the usual talking did not work for OP. The situation I want to avoid : OP goes to some admin staff claiming "instructor X cancelled the class due to lack of students". The employee there knows this is fair reason but does not know if the claim is true, but he won't say he/she is suspicious, nor will ask for written proof, he/she'll claim he/she "needs to check something", and OP request gets ignored because this worker does not even know who is instructor X and how to contact him, who also didn't send a memo warning the staff in advance.

Comment: @terdon : What I'm suggesting: Go to the instructor with your phone, ask if you can take his contact info (he might be uncomfortable with giving his personal phone, but an email should be okay). Instead of telling the adm staff to call him or send him an email, OP can ask the instructor: "can I turn on my phone camera and we explain together that the class was cancelled?", so no "sitting" through, no production, no more than a whatsapp message. The thing is that this authenticates both the instructor and the circumstance. Might sound unnecessary, but OP's problem should have been solved by now

Comment: @Mefitico yeah, that's what I thought you meant. As the instructor, I would find that incredibly intrusive (not everyone likes to be in videos) and as the HR person I would find it very annoying and more work than I am willing to do. All you need is a signed statement from the instructor. A video just makes everything harder in my view.

Comment: @ceejayoz Chargeback is far easier than dealing with court. And, if chargeback failed (which seems pretty unlikely to me, but I suppose it varies by card issuer,) then I would assume the small claims option would still be open (assuming that it was in the first place, absent an arbitration clause or some such thing.) But IANAL, so perhaps my assumption there is wrong.

Comment: The department that processes the chargeback has no influence on admissions whatsoever. I got a contract at a bank while I was in the middle of suing them. Successfully, too.

Comment: @ceejayoz  The charge was for a course, not for a single class. You can't fight a chargeback on the basis of "Well, I did *some* of what I said I would do". At worst, they'll be able to get it moved to a partial chargeback, but that's unlikely.

Answer (score 62):

> Would this hurt my chances at getting into the grad school later on?

Practices vary, but probably not.

> Will it hurt me later on?

Very likely.  You probably will not be able to complete a graduate degree if the university thinks you owe money.

> I should just let myself be robbed?

No, you should insist on a refund.  Ask the instructor and their department to help you get a refund.  Ask the registration department again.  Ask to speak to the head of that department.

HR is probably the wrong department to contact.

Comment: Indeed, you will probably not be able to **start** a graduate degree if the university thinks you owe money.  You could still be admitted, but they likely won't let you register for any classes until your debt is cleared.

Comment: OP may register but will not get a degree which will be withheld. Strongly recommended to make everything formal rather than operating by chargeback.

Comment: Oh yes. When I was about to graduate, I was told I still owed some money (which I was unaware of) and would have to pay it before I would be able to get my degree. The amount outstanding: 25p (roughly 33 cents US).

Comment: Yeah, registration and/or the bursar's office would be the places to contact, not HR.

Comment: @NateEldredge If the university 'thinks you owe money' after they have had a chargeback they would be in severe need of some re-education. It's not even proper accounting, let alone law.

Comment: @user207421: How so?  A chargeback just reverses the payment you made.  It doesn't erase the underlying debt and if it was valid, you may still owe it.  The university can sue to enforce it, and they can certainly refuse you any further services until it's paid.  If a court says the debt is invalid, that's another story, but the credit card company is not a court.

Comment: @user207421 https://www.google.com/search?q=collections+after+chargeback

Answer (score 29):

HR is not your friend. I'd recommend talking to any or all of the following people:

- The instructor who cancelled the class
- The department chair/boss of the instructor who cancelled the class (after trying the instructor first)
- The undergraduate ombudsman
- The Dean of Students

You should also figure out what, from the university's point of view, "the instructor cancelled the class" means. Does the class appear on the university's list of currently ongoing classes? If no, talk to the registration department or to general university administrators. If yes, then talking to the instructor or their immediate boss is more likely to be helpful.

The ombudsman (if such a position exists at your university) can be a wonderful resource. They will not intervene directly, but they will give general advice and explain how the university's bureaucracy works.

University bureaucracies can be infuriating. Good luck!

Comment: I often need to remind myself this line *"HR is not your friend."* they may look friendly and act friendly but they're not your friend. You may have friends in HR, but the HR itself as a department is never a friend nor friendly. Even the most helpful ones are still looking out for the company first and foremost. +1

Comment: HR is the wrong department to talk to for a student, but I’m sorry, I have to downvote this repetition of the *toxic myth* that “HR is not your friend”. HR being your friend is a function of the workplace toxicity. HR *can* be your friend, and in a reasonable company they *are*. Don’t dismiss them without reason.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Do they ever help out low-ranking people address a serious complaint with their company or university? I thought the answer was no, but it could be that I'm misinformed.

Comment: it's not a 'toxic myth' at all, that's completely ridiculous to say.  HR is not there for the benefit of the employee, or in this case student.  They exist to protect the company.

Comment: @academic To the extent that this is within their power and responsibility, yes, absolutely. In all the workplaces I’ve had so far HR was helpful and proactive, and has, in two instances in particular, helped me personally (in one instance a group of people) enforce my interest against that of my employer. The claim that HR’s job is to protect the employers against *employees* is not true in general, and is indicative of malicious or incompetent personnel, not a natural law.

Comment: @academic well to be fair they certainly can be of help.  But just because they do occasionally act in the benefit of the low-ranking person doesn't make them an ally.  The analogy would be mandatory arbitration.  Just because the arbitrators don't always side with the company doesn't mean there isn't bias in that direction.

Comment: @eps “HR is not there for the benefit of the employee […]. They exist to protect the company.” — That’s true only in toxic workplaces (pretty much by definition, because it’s inherently adversarial). Healthy companies define HR’s role entirely differently, namely to *help* employees navigate the bureaucratic corners of their job.

Comment: @KonradRudolf HR’s job is to protect the company, in general. Sometimes that means protecting the company from their employees, sometimes it means protecting them from their own incompetence by helping out employees who might sue the company.

Comment: Either way, can we all agree that saying *HR is not your friend* is a bit sensationalist, and doesn't really convey any specific or actionable message? It's probably more helpful to just simply state what HR's role is (or is not).

Comment: @dwizum I don't think so--The sensationalist aspect is balanced by the amazing level of screwed some have attained by trusting HR.  Your safest bet is to always chant "HR is not your friend" under your breath.  If you are wrong, there is absolutely no harm done, but if it matters, that simple chant could save your career.

Comment: @BillK I agree one should be cautious about trusting HR, but you are wrong to say that there is no cost associated with not trusting them. Not trusting people absolutely has a cost (it means you can't rely on what they say and have to check it yourself).

Comment: I don't think it's even a trust issue. It seems that the issue is that people seek the wrong help from HR. They go to HR as a generic helpdesk. Then they get upset when HR doesn't unquestionably remove their obstacle, or it explodes in their face because HR has other (legitimate) motives. Explaining what things HR is and isn't there for seems better than mindlessly repeating a negative mantra. If you go to HR for appropriate things, you may find them very friendly! But first, you have to know which things are appropriate. Telling someone "HR is not your friend" doesn't accomplish this.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica EXACTLY, you should not rely on what HR says and check for yourself.  Perfect summary, thank you!

Comment: @BillK Chanting "HR is not your friend" is no more or less sensible than chanting "IT is not your friend", "Janitorial is not your friend", "Accounting is not your friend", or "The secretarial staff is not your friend". -- For some bizarre reason HR gets specifically called out on this when they're no more or less likely to be your friend than any other part of an organization. -- HR is no more or less your friend than the instructor, the Dean of Students or the department head is. HR might not be the best people to talk to, but that has nothing to do with them being your friend or not.

Answer (score 14):

Asking your bank for a chargeback may be a technical solution to the problem, but it is not a real solution. You may get your money back but if the University thinks you still owe them, they will hold your certificates until the debt is settled.

Consider shifting your focus from the money to the actual source of disagreement. Ultimately, it is a question of who is responsible for the cancellation of the course. From the first glance, it seems obvious that the University should accept the responsibility and refund the students, at least from what I can read in your question. But it's not happened yet. You need to understand better the university regulations relevant to this situation. You also need to understand better why the person in HR department believes they don't have to refund you.

Whom can you ask for help or advice? Can student union help? The head of the department, perhaps? Is there an external regulator in your country, e.g. [Office for Students](https://www.officeforstudents.org.uk/) in the UK?

Also, is HR the right person to ask? Should you consult student finance, perhaps? Do you have an invoice / receipt  for the money you payed and is there an address on this document of someone you can contact with issues?

Your situation looks strange to me and I hope it will resolve itself easily as soon as you find right people to talk to. Good luck.

Comment: If the university thinks you owe them money after a chargeback they are in need of both legal and accounting education. This is simply not correct.

Comment: @user207421 It's quite correct. The chargeback is just the bank refusing to facilitate the payment. It does not do anything to change the status of your legal obligation to pay the university. The bank can even decide that the debt is 100% legally valid but still decide to do the chargeback because the payment violates some rule of theirs. That wouldn't mean you didn't owe the merchant the money. (How could it be otherwise? The bank or payment company decides whether the chargeback happens or not. Only a court can rule that you have no obligation to pay.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz If I make a refund to a customer, whether voluntarily or otherwise, I can't keep it on my books as an account receivable. I will never receive the funds and it would be a mis-statement of the company's financial position to carry it as an asset. I have to make a journal entry to balance the books.

Comment: @user207421 You do not know that you will never receive the funds until you try to collect them. You can file a suit. You can place the account for collections. That the bank will not intermediate the payment of the funds doesn't mean the amount isn't owed or that the customer will not pay. Neither the bank nor the payment company can make that decision.

Comment: @user207421 Classic example: Someone buys something from you. You charge their credit card because you have an authorization on file. The customer files a chargeback claiming the authorization expired. You check, they're right, the authorization expired. They still owe you the money, right? They don't get the thing for free, do they? (They might even have an authorization for another card that's current and on file that you can bill immediately.)

Comment: Still pretty ridiculous that the university claims you owe the full course bill after receiving just 1 lesson then the course being cancelled ... a semester by rough estimation is 26 weeks - which makes the 650 just $25 per week .. let them deduct 1 weeks worth .. but 625 is to be paid back in my eyes. Only that HR is really not the right place to fight for your claim as already hinted

Comment: @user207421 OP making a chargeback is not remotely the same thing as the university giving a refund.

Answer (score 9):

When I was an undergrad I had some similar problem. At my school there was a special student advocacy office called the "Student Conflict Resolution Center" that was able to do... well, exactly what the name says. They were tasked with helping students navigate this kind of bureaucratic headache (among many other things). I explained the problem to them, they listened and understood it, and then they fixed it in a matter of days. It as a big weight off my shoulders.

You might want to see if you have a similar resource at your school. If you do, definitely get in touch with them.

Comment: This might be handled through an Ombudsman/Ombuds office at some universities, which often serves a similar function (with a remit broader than just student conflicts).

Comment: This office would otherwise be called the Ombudsman's Office at many schools, and is a part of that office at my alma mater. I think the SCRC was formed with a mandate to specifically advocate for students.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the correct term for a class to have enough students to be worth teaching is "to make."  If the class officially didn't make, you should get a refund of course: the school decided the course doesn't even exist and can hardly make you pay.  In this case, the school would not allow the professor to submit a grade, so it's out of their control.  The prof could decide to teach you *anyway* but they couldn't submit a grade for it as the class simply doesn't exist.

If the course *did* make but your prof is literally refusing to do their job (this happens thanks to tenure) then you have a tricky position: even when tenured professors refuse to hold class or office hours or unfairly fail all their students (there have been cases of this) it can be contractually almost impossible for the school to remedy.  From the school's perspective there is a class and your prof will eventually enter a grade for it, or not (which also happens).  You'll eventually have credit hours for it at that school, even if the class isn't meeting.  The prof might be penalized, but since you would be getting credit hours the school may not wish to refund.  In this case what can you do?

If you want the *teaching* then you're out of luck.  Prof says he won't teach.  (Though idea: if the same course is offered at a different time perhaps you could just switch sections?  You shouldn't have to, but just an idea.  Maybe the second prof can't grade your assignments, which is a PITA for them, but lets you listen to lectures at least, which shouldn't put them out.)

If you want the class *knowledge* and don't need the actual weekly teaching part, perhaps you could self-study and the prof would administer tests for you at mutual convenience?   That should be minimal effort for the prof and they might be amenable.  If you  additionally need some tutelage perhaps this could be available in office hours?

If you want the class *credit* and don't care about the knowledge you might be able to just get an auto-A or pass from the prof on just a verbal commitment to study the text.

Comment: Tenure means profs can't be fired for exercising academic freedoms, e.g. teaching courses or doing research which is not "liked" by the University for some reason. Tenure gives no protection if profs are not doing their job. Profs who refuse to attend the class can be fired for not fulfilling their academic duties.

Comment: "Tenure gives no protection if profs are not doing their job."  @DmitrySavostyanov if you research this Chronicle of Higher Education you'll find many cases where tenure does exactly that.  The theoretical reason for this is, I assume, to keep an institution from trumping up a job performance reason to dismiss a professor who they in fact want to fire because they're coming up with new ideas that threaten the powers in society.  "We can't fire Copernicus for his dangerous Heliocentric theory but he was a minute late to office hours so we'll just sack him for that."

Comment: I agree in principle, but there is a vast difference between being one minute late to office hours and dropping the course completely after the first couple of lectures.